# How to add tags to posts using checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to build a many-to-many association through tagging between posts and tags. Users can create posts with tags by checking the existed tags. But I don't know how to create a nested form and save the association.

My form

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "post[tag_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Tag.all.each do |tag| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "post[tag_ids][]", tag.id, @post.tag_ids.include?(tag.id) %>
      <%= tag.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

posts controller here:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:text)
    end
end
```

Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need to have a nested form in this case. Rails automagically figures out the association, when given the attribute :tag_ids

This is what I did for a multiselect form_helper, which would need minor changes for a check_box helper

```
f.select :tag_ids, Tag.all.collect {|tag| [tag.name, tag.id]}, {}, :multiple => true
```